# Better/faster algorithm to rotate an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, data-structures

**Given an array, rotate the array to the right by k steps, where k is non-negative.**

**Example 1:**

**Input:** [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] and k = 3

**Output:** [5,6,7,1,2,3,4]

**Explanation:**

Step 1: [7,1,2,3,4,5,6]

Step 2: [6,7,1,2,3,4,5]

Step 3: [5,6,7,1,2,3,4]

My Solution:

```
var rotate = function(nums, k) {
while(k>0){ 
 let lastelm = nums[nums.length-1];
  for(let i =nums.length; i>0;i--){
    temp = nums[i-1];
    nums[i-1] = nums[i-2];    
  }
  nums[0]=lastelm
  k--;
 }     
};
```

I think my solution is O(k*nums.length)

I am modifying the entire array as many times as k

What could be a better approach to this?

Comment: I think this belongs at https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @mplungjan I disagree.  Performance is _always_ important in code, the only question is to what _degree_.  How fast something is in big O notation, which this question clearly mentions, is a purely objective measure.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.slice` to take two slices out of an array - one starting from the beginning, ending in the middle, and the other slice starting in the middle and ending at the end. Then just re-combine them in reverse order:

```js
const rotate = (nums, k) => [...nums.slice(-k), ...nums.slice(0, -k)];
console.log(rotate([1,2,3,4,5,6,7], 1));
console.log(rotate([1,2,3,4,5,6,7], 3));
```

If you *have* to mutate the existing array, then:

```js
const rotate = (nums, k) => {
  const moveAfter = new Array(k).concat(nums.slice(0, -k));
  Object.assign(nums, nums.slice(-k), moveAfter);
  return nums;
};
console.log(rotate([1,2,3,4,5,6,7], 1));
console.log(rotate([1,2,3,4,5,6,7], 3));
```

If `k` may be larger than the length of the array, use modulo on it first:

```js
const rotate = (nums, kPossiblyOutOfRange) => {
  const k = kPossiblyOutOfRange % nums.length;
  return [...nums.slice(-k), ...nums.slice(0, -k)];
}
console.log(rotate([1,2,3,4,5,6,7], 1));
console.log(rotate([1,2,3,4,5,6,7], 8));
console.log(rotate([1,2,3,4,5,6,7], 3));
```

Comment: Interesting, but seems to be buggy (unless I'm missing something):
rotate([1,2,3,4,5,6,7], 1) -> [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2] 
rotate([1,2,3,4,5,6,7], 0) -> [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1]

Comment: Oh, I was rotating to the left, have to pass a negative index instead

Comment: Another findings I'd like to highlight: 1) this does not edit original array, but returns new one; 2) does not work for k > 7

Comment: @CertainPerformance I think you need something like `k = k % nums.length;` somewhere in your code

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is just to keep track of the shift when you read or write to the array. I.e. store a constant 'shift' and when you read or write from the array at index i, make the adjustment to (i + shift) % (array size).

Comment: This is constant time, or O(1)

Answer (score 0):

[unshift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) combined with [pop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) seems to do a trick:

```
var rotate = function(nums, k) {
    while (k > 0) { 
        nums.unshift(nums.pop());
        k--;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var rotate = function(nums, k) {
  k = k % nums.length;
  revNums(nums, 0, nums.length - 1);
  revNums(nums, 0, k -1);
  revNums(nums, k , nums.length - 1);
};

var revNums = function(arr, start, end){
while(start < end){
    [arr[start], arr[end]] = [arr[end], arr[start]];
    start++;
    end--;
 }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).